# Does google-cloud-datastore offer more than one database

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, datasource

Currently, on my cloud project, I have one database which contains kinds. My question is it possible to create another database that can have different kinds?
[Illustration for current database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EVFX.png)

Comment: Why would you need to have another DB to store different kinds? The point of Datastore is that you can add as many kinds as you want, and each object of the same kind does not even need to have the same schema (it's a schemaless DB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to create another [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview) database in a single project. A workaround could be using separate projects and [adding an authorized IAM user or service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting_access_to_team_members) to both projects in order to access both in their respective projects.

Also, maybe a [multi tenancy strategy](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/multitenancy) may allow you to customize data values for each tenant, while keeping the same data schema for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

GCP has recently introduced a way to create more than one database for datastore.

As for 29.08.2023, it is in preview.

You can read more about that on the [official GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-databases?&_ga=2.21434232.-2104087223.1685433537#create_a_database).